# PEP 342 code snippet with `yield`s outside function. Is it no longer supported?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine, yield

[PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) says:

> A yield-expression must always be parenthesized except when it occurs at the top-level expression on the right-hand side of an assignment. So
>
> ```
> x = yield 42
> x = yield
> x = 12 + (yield 42)
> x = 12 + (yield)
> foo(yield 42)
> foo(yield)
> ```
>
> are all legal

I tried out this code and got `SyntaxError: 'yield' outside function`. Is this old syntax no longer supported? What was the original behavior?

Comment: You can only ever yield in the body of a function.

Comment: `yield` has never been allowed outside of a function.  Those are code fragments, not complete runnable pieces of code.

Comment: That code snippet is just listing possible ways to use the statement, it's implied that all of those happen in a function

Comment: [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions): _The yield expression is used when defining a generator function or an asynchronous generator function and **thus can only be used in the body of a function definition**_